# Simpleform ForbiddenAttributesError in Rails 4 and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, simple-form

I'm trying to debug ForbiddenAttributesError in Rails 4

Below is my form:

```
= simple_form_for(@venue, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }, :wrapper => "horizontal", defaults: { :input_html => { class: "form-control"}, label_html: { class: "col-lg-4" } } ) do |f|
    = f.error_notification

    .form-inputs
        = f.input :name
        = f.association :user, label_method: :email, prompt: "Please select an owner", :input_html => { class: "chosen" }
        = f.input :colour, input_html: { :colourpicker => true }
        = f.input :background_image
        = simple_form_image_paperclip('Top background', f, :top_background, @venue_background_url)
        = simple_form_image_paperclip('Logo', f, :uploaded_file, @venue_logo_url)
        = f.input :whats_new
        = f.input :personal_map
        = f.input :display_webcast_rating
        = f.input :display_other_content_rating
        = f.input :closed_event_redirect
        = f.input :display_on_demand_status
        = f.input :display_original_broadcast_date
        = f.input :venue_reports_url
        = f.input :support_message
        = f.input :venue_comments
    .form-actions
        = f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

This is my strong parameters:

```
    def venue_params
      params.require(:venue).permit(:name, :user_id, :colour, :background_image,
        :whats_new, :personal_map, :display_webcast_rating, :display_other_content_rating, :closed_event_redirect,
        :display_on_demand_status, :display_original_broadcast_date, :venue_reports_url, :support_message, :venue_comments,
        top_background_attributes: [:assets], uploaded_file_attributes: [:assets])
    end
```

Is there anything wrong with the fields or somewhere I need to look at to fix this problem?

from development log:

```
Started POST "/venues" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-20 00:01:24 +1100
Processing by VenuesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sFhGfjIpjnRE/XXgY1rwK0D2jYdlbp8bVSNW5+g7DAY=", "venue"=>{"name"=>"", "user_id"=>"", "colour"=>"", "whats_new"=>"0", "personal_map"=>"0", "display_webcast_rating"=>"0", "display_other_content_rating"=>"0", "closed_event_redirect"=>"0", "display_on_demand_status"=>"0", "display_original_broadcast_date"=>"0", "venue_reports_url"=>"", "support_message"=>"", "venue_comments"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Venue"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUploadedFile Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "uploaded_files".* FROM "uploaded_files" WHERE "uploaded_files"."imageable_id" = $1 AND "uploaded_files"."imageable_type" = $2 ORDER BY "uploaded_files"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["imageable_id", 1], ["imageable_type", "User"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
  activemodel (4.0.0) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:21:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:192:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
```

Comment: Got any more info on the error? Any specifics?

Comment: @RichPeck I just added a few top lines from `development.log` file

Comment: Are you using the [`protected_attributes`](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) gem at all?

Comment: try wrap params like `{top_background_attributes: [:assets]}, {uploaded_file_attributes: [:assets]}`

Comment: @Monk_Code I just tried it but same error

Comment: what input type of this `top_background_attributes`?

Comment: it's for `polymorphic` relations for `paperclip` model from `venue` model

Comment: @Monk_Code how would one normally debug this kind of error in Rails 4?

Comment: you need declare empty array in params `top_background_attributes: [], uploaded_file_attributes: []`